# Creating folders from values in a CSV

Tags: file, powershell, csv

I am working on a small portion of a larger scripting solution in which i need to create folders based on values stored in a CSV and then move the applicable files in to the new folder according to values in a column of the csv.

The format of the CSV:

```
fileName, folder
AC002       Y
AC034       Y
AC001
X2400       Y
AC006
AC007
AC009       Y
```

This is the code I have working for the problem:

```
$sourceDir = read-host "Please enter source Dir:"

$csv = import-csv C:\scripts\files\files.csv
$csv | where {$_.folder -eq 'Y'} | % {
            $path = $sourceDir + "\" + $_.fileName 
            if(-not (Test-Path $path))
            {
                md $path

            }#end if
        }#end for
```

The next step will probably be a bit more tricky.

Thanks to Shay Levy for the help, 
Craig

Comment: all files and folders in the csv file are located under $sourceDir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will create the folder even if it exists. We can change that if you want and create only folders that do not exist:

```
$csv = import-csv C:\scripts\files\files.csv
$csv | where {$_.folder -eq 'y'} | `
       foreach { md -force (join-path $sourceDir $_.fileName) }
```

Comment: Thank you very much I had never seen the join-path cmdlet before. This works a treat, I wasnt sure how to filter the fields before a for loop and its blindingly obvious now. I have edited my original to show how i know how to create folders only if they dont exist, if you know a way of improving this code I would love to see it, just wanted to show im thinking of how ot do it myself.