# Can information pulled from a csv be converted to a string for use in cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to write a script that pulls information about local servers from a csv file when the user enters a geographical location (the csv is organised into two columns, 'location' and 'servername').  I thought I had had some success with this when using the `foreach-object` command with wmi, as in this example:

```
$l = (read-host "Enter Location")
import-csv -path C:\users\reillyf\desktop\location.csv | where {$_.location -eq $l} | select -property servername | foreach-object { get-wmiobject win32_printer} |  Select Name, ShareName,PortName,DriverName
```

However, this was merely displaying the values for the localhost, without errors (`get-wmiobject` does not usually take pipeline input, which is why this didn't work).  My original idea was to store the output of `import-csv -path C:\users\reillyf2\desktop\location.csv | where {$_.location -eq $l} | select -property servername` in a variable and then drop that variable into a parameter, but that always produced an error which stated that the parameter contained a value that was null.  Why this happened can be seen if you look at the contents of such a variable:

```
PS C:\Users\reillyf> $l = (read-host "Enter Location")
$server = import-csv -path C:\users\reillyf\desktop\location.csv | where {$_.location -eq $l} | select -property servername
Enter Location: York

PS C:\Users\reillyf> $server

servername                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
----------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
SHCGBY01DC01
```

It would appear that because the result which is obtained is not a string, it cannot be dropped into a parameter or piped to cmdlets.  Is there any way that this can be converted to a simple text string which can be dropped into commands (like a variable created by `read-host`) I have using `convertfrom-csv`, which did not seem to change the presence of 'servername' and the separating line in the output.

Maybe this just can't be done - however if it can it would allow me to write an easy to use script with the minimum of hassle, and without needing to hard code the server names in question into it (useful if they change). Any ideas?

Comment: I have just found the answer to my problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385512/creating-folders-from-values-in-a-csv?rq=1, this is awesome! Sorry if I wasted your time here

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the linked answer actually addresses your problem.

Instead of just doing `select servername`, you have to do `select -expand servername` and it will "expand" the property and return that alone instead of an object with that property.

Comment: Here's what I wound up doing, maybe a bit of a roundabout way but it works a treat: `$l = (read-host 'Enter Location (type b to go back)');
$csv = import-csv -path C:\scripts\location.csv;
$csv | where {$_.location -eq $l} | % { $server = $_.servername }`